# How to pass JSON to a Docker container at runtime?

Tags: json, bash, docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I need to pass `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` as an environment variable using the `docker run`.

*I am only using service credentials locally for staging. Container will be pushed to Railway.*

*docker-compose.yaml* is not an option.

`docker run -it --rm --env-file ./.env test-file` returns the following error:

`docker: poorly formatted environment: variable '"type": "service_account",' contains whitespaces.`

**Example .env**

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}'
```

Comment: Variable just is string. If your application can read `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from file, so you should mount a json file or try encode to string and decode inside docker.

Comment: You need to place that value all on one line. `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='{"type":"service_account","project_id":"","private_key_id":"","private_key":"","client_email":"","client_id":"","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url":"","universe_domain":"googleapis.com"}'`

Comment: The recommended method is to first base-64 encode the JSON. Use that string for the environment variable. Do not use raw JSON strings for environment variables. In your app, base-64 decode the the value back to a JSON string. You do not state where you are running the container or how, but another method is to use volume mounts. Your app can then reference the filename instead of the contents. Note: `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` must be a filename. Setting the value to the contents will not work with Google SDKs. That means using a volume mount if that is supported in your environment.

Comment: I recommend not to use the Service Account key files because it's not secure. Your user credential are enough. Here an article I wrote to achieve that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da

Comment: Please update your question with more details on how you are running containers. @guillaumeblaquiere comment and article remind me that there are better and more secure methods of running containers in Google Cloud. Details matter in your case. Guillaume has written many excellent articles. They will help you understand how to implement features in a secure manner.

Comment: @JohnHanley I took your first recommendation with the base64 encoding. I am running the container via Railway.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to mount the volume containing the file into the container. Show you can read the json file from the path.

Comment: Please provide some sample code to support your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
docker run -it --rm -v path/to/your/key.json:/tmp/keys/key.json:ro -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/key.json yourimage
```